# Add to quote functionality in magento?

Tags: magento, quote

I want to add, add to quote functionality in my magento site ?

like :http://www.belgosweet.be/product.php?product=85&cat=20  this site.

Thanks

Comment: Email cart extension can help https://magecomp.com/magento-email-cart.html

Answer (score 3):

You do understand that there is no straight answer for that.

What you are asking for involves modifying several core files and functionality. Maybe you would be interested in an already free available solution something like this:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Cart2Quote/extension/5495/cart2quote_customer_quotation

There are other solutions with payment if you want too :)

HTH